# Manage functionality module jars in Spring

Tags: java, spring, module

Suppose I have several modules in my java application, these modules are optional and the presence and absence of their respective jars determine the presence of absence of their functionality. How would I make this happen with Spring?

For example, I have a core class with references to a controller interface. Somehow I need that if the jar implementing this interface is present in my classpath, Spring injects it with the appropriate bean, else, it's null.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can create a java class scanning all classes of your classpath and check if they implement a interface. If your application gets bigger this will slow down, because runtime is O(N) and will take a lot of memory on initialization.

2.) If you want to develope a bigger application and also want to use spring, i think an osgi-container with gemini-blueprint as spring extension could fit.

Maybe both of my options don't fit your needs because your question is to short and not detailed enough. About which kind of application are we talking? Do you need 3. party libs?